# I need to convert xlsx file to xml

Tags: c#, excel, xml, xlsx

To do so I have used the Aspose.cells nuget package but this library is for evaluation only.
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("Book1.xlsx");

```
//Load your source workbook
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("Book1.xlsx");
```

//Save as Excel 2003 Spreadsheet XML
workbook.Save("Spreadsheet.xml");

//Save as plain XML data
XmlSaveOptions xmlSaveOptions = new XmlSaveOptions();
workbook.Save("data.xml", xmlSaveOptions);

So the library is converting like above.

but I am searching for a free library or any other method. I am doing this in C#.
So please help me with this.

Comment: Doesn't work very well.  XLSX is Microsoft excel format and xml is a text format.  The xml created isn't compatible with Open XML.  I've done it before and the XML created isn't very useful.

Comment: Basically I need to convert xlsx into xml so that I am able to compare two xlsx file.

Comment: An XLSX file is already XML. Change the extension to ZIP and unzip it..

Comment: I would save as CSV and compare.  Much easier.

Comment: I need to compare them at Unit testing

Comment: https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-xml.htm

Comment: Install free spire.xls via nuget: Install-Package FreeSpire.XLS and follow this [documentation](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Export-Excel-to-XML-and-Import-XML-to-Excel.html) to save xlsx file as xml.

Comment: [Convert XLSX to XML](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/excel/docs/questions/c-sharp-export-to-excel/#anchor-c-num-export-to-xml-file) in two lines of code using IronXL. Free for development, and a license is [much cheaper than aspose cells](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/excel/blog/compare-to-other-components/aspose-cells-alternative-by-ironxl/#anchor-comparing-licenses-and-pricing-for-the-ironxl-and-aspose-cells-excel-libraries).